# How to store salt and IV in file cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, encryption, aes, salt

So I have implemented salts and IVs, but the decryption is now a bit buggy. Of course, I need both the salt and IV for decryption as well, but the user can't enter that... I need to be able to store both the salt and IV in the encrypted file, then retrieve the salt and IV when the user is decrypting the file. How would I go about doing this? How would I go about storing and retrieving that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter said, the initialization vector and the salt for key derivation should be stored together with the encrypted file, in a header or such.

Instead of creating your own ad-hoc file format for encrypted storage, have a look at the OpenPGP message format (as used by both PGP and GnuPG, and maybe other programs). It is specified in [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880). You will likely not have to implement all of it, but grab the portions that you need for your application.

As an added bonus, the user can then use PGP/GPG (with the right options and the password/key) to decrypt the data, if your program should somehow cease to work.

Answer (score 0):

Store them along with the ciphertext. You'll need to come up with a suitable file format in which to do it; a keyed archiver will make it easy.

Comment: Yes I figured that, but how would I create my own file format?